# JavaScript Execute Array of Functions & Return True If All Return True

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, iteration

Couldn't really find an answer for this.
I have a function which should allow users to pass it "checks" (functions that returns `true` or `false`). The checks will run on a large number of items. For each item I want to know if all the checks returned true.

```
function foo(checksArray) { //checksArray: [func1, func2, func3]
  var itemList = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  for (item of itemList)
    if (checkAllFunctions(item))
      doSomething();
}
```

How can I do it? Obviously I can iterate over each function with a `for` loop but I suspect there might be a better way. Maybe there's even a one-liner.

Thanks for any help guys.

Edit: I guess there isn't really any point in keeping running even though one of checks returned false. If it can stop right there, that's even better!

Comment: Should all the functions get called even if one of them returns false, or should `foo` bomb out as soon as possible?

Comment: is the `doSomething` method `sync` or `async`?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Edited question, I should have mentioned it beforehand. @AdityaParab Should be `sync`. @Andreas I'll check them, thanks!

Comment: The simplest approach is to use `Array.prototype.every`. Something like this `itemList.every( item => checksArray.every(check => check(item)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forEach` to take up each element of `itemList`. Inside that loop, use `every` to check if every function in `checksArray` passes.

```
function foo(checksArray) { //checksArray: [func1, func2, func3]
  var itemList = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  itemList.forEach(function(item) {
    if (checksArray.every(function(check) { return check(item); })) doSomething();
  });
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Close to @YuryTarabanko's comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple flag for that. Try something like this:

```
function foo(checksArray) { //checksArray: [func1, func2, func3]
    var itemList = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    var flag = true;

    for (item of itemList)
        flag = checkElement(item); // check single element, not all

        if(flag){
            // here you can check your state after every single item
        }
    }

    if(flag){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be missing an iterator? I don't see a reference to `checksArray`. Also, I mentioned I know I can do this with a loop but wanted to know if there's a shorter/cleaner/faster way.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily shorter, but cleaner and correct:

```
function foo (checksArray) {
    var itemList = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var meetsAllCriteria = itemList.every(function (item) {
        return checkAllFunctions(item);
    });
    if (meetsAllCriteria) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually want the `doSomething()` to run every time the checks for an item return true. `checkAllFunctions(item)` is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Are you using `checksArray`?

Comment: Also, how is `function(item) { return checkAllFunctions(item); }` different from just `checkAllFunctions`?